# Read lines of a txt file and organize in a JSON file

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, fs

I have a text file where each line is separated into 4 categories by colons and I want to put this into a JSON file, where each category is a value to the corresponding name in the JSON file.

Example `data.txt` file:

```
Date1:cat1:dog1:bug1
Date2:cat2:dog2:bug2
Date3:cat3:dog3:bug3
```

Example JSON file:

```
{
  "Date1": {
    "cat": "cat1",
    "dog": "dog1",
    "bug": "bug1"
  },
  "Date2": {
    "cat": "cat2",
    "dog": "dog2",
    "bug": "bug2"
    ...
  ...
}
```

I've never used JSON before but I think that's how to format it. How would I sort each line using the colons as markers for the next value and store it in the JSON file with the correct name using JavaScript and Node.js?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the csv package if you don't want to handle parsing csv file by yourself.

```
const fs = require("fs");
const csv = require("csv");

const result = {};
const keys = ["cat", "dog", "bug"]

// Read data
const readStream = fs.createReadStream("yourfile.txt");

// Parser
const parser = csv.parse({ delimiter: ":" });

parser.on("data", (chunk) => {
result[chunk[0]] = {};
    for(let i = 1; i < chunk.length; i ++) {
        result[chunk[0]][keys[i - 1]] = chunk[i];
    }
});

parser.on("end", () => {
    console.log(result);
});

readStream.pipe(parser);
```

Comment: where can I find documentation on how to use the csv parser? particularly the parser.on("data") and "end" lines

Answer (score 1):

If your JSON has this defined structure you can go about it with the following code:

```
import * as fs from 'fs';

/* If you have a large file this is a bad Idea, refer to reading from a stream 
 * From zhangjinzhou's answer
 */
const file = fs.readFileSync('path/to/data.txt', 'utf8');

const json = file.split(/\n|\r\n/).map(line => {
  const values = line.split(":");
  let obj = {}

  obj[values[0]] =  {
    cat: values[1],
    dog: values[2],
    bug: values[3],
  };

  return obj
}).reduce((acc, current) => Object.assign(acc, current), {})
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [**RegExp**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) and [**Array#forEach**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), convert the string to lines, then iterate over them and fill up the `object` with the corresponding data via:

```js
const dataFileContent = 
`Date1:cat1:dog1:bug1
Date2:cat2:dog2:bug2
Date3:cat3:dog3:bug3`;

function processData(data) {
  // convert to lines
  const lines = data.match(/[^\r\n]+/g) || [];  
  const object = {};
  
  // iterate over the lines
  lines.forEach(line => {
    const parts = line.split(':');    
    const main = parts.shift();
    const pattern = /^(.*?)(\d+)$/;
    
    // create an object for each main part
    object[main] = {};    
    
    // fill each main part with the sub parts
    parts.forEach(part => {
      const match = part.match(pattern) || [];
      const key = match[1];
      const value = match[2];
            
      if (match) {
        object[main][key] = key + value;
      }
    });
  }); 
  
  return object;
}

const processedData = processData(dataFileContent);
console.log(processedData);
```

Then convert the `processedData` to JSON by using [**JSON.stringify**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) and save it to a file via:

```
const fs = require('fs');

...
// processData
...

const json = JSON.stringify(processedData);
fs.writeFile('my_json_file.json', json, 'utf8');
```

For larger files, consider using [**Streams**](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html) in Node.js as suggested by [**@zhangjinzhou**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51623567/10079674).